# ajax erro function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function getWikiData(marker)  {

    var wikiurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
action=opensearch&search=" +
      marker.title + "&format=json&callback=wikiCallback";

    $.ajax({

      url: wikiurl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      // jasonp: "callback",
      success: function(response) {
        var summary = response[2][0];
        var article = response[3][0];
        var articleUrl = article;

        console.log(response);
        console.log(response[2][0]);
        console.log(response[3][0]);


        self.infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2><p>' + 
summary + '</p>' + '<a title="go to wikipedia article" href="' + articleUrl 
+ '">> go to wikipedia article</a>'); self.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      }

    })


    error: function(){
          alert("An Error Occurred Loading Wikipedia Article. Please try 
again later")
    };



}
```

I'm trying to add error function to my ajax

Console.log error

script.js:255 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

line 255 would be error:function(error){
not sure why it won't read my code.

Comment: Error has to be inside your ajax function, and you are putting it outside of it, not to mention unclosed `(`

Answer (score 0):

Error function is part of the AJAX and hence it needs to be inside it. Try this below code:

```js
function getWikiData(marker) {

  var wikiurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
  action = opensearch & search = " +
  marker.title + "&format=json&callback=wikiCallback";

  $.ajax({

    url: wikiurl,
    dataType: "jsonp",
    // jasonp: "callback",
    success: function(response) {
      var summary = response[2][0];
      var article = response[3][0];
      var articleUrl = article;

      console.log(response);
      console.log(response[2][0]);
      console.log(response[3][0]);


      self.infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2><p>' +
        summary + '</p>' + '<a title="go to wikipedia article" href="' + articleUrl +
        '">> go to wikipedia article</a>');
      self.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    },
    error: function() {
      alert("An Error Occurred Loading Wikipedia Article. Please try again later ")
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error:function() was outside of ajax call. move error function to inside ajax call

```js
function getWikiData(marker)  {

    var wikiurl = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=" + marker.title +"&format=json&callback=wikiCallback";

    $.ajax({

      url: wikiurl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      // jasonp: "callback",
      success: function(response) {
        var summary = response[2][0];
        var article = response[3][0];
        var articleUrl = article;

        console.log(response);
        console.log(response[2][0]);
        console.log(response[3][0]);


        self.infoWindow.setContent('<h2>' + marker.title + '</h2><p>' + 
summary + '</p>' + '<a title="go to wikipedia article" href="' + articleUrl 
+ '">> go to wikipedia article</a>'); self.infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      },
       error: function(){
          alert("An Error Occurred Loading Wikipedia Article. Please try again later")
    }


    });
}
```